# Dual boot Windows 10 and elementary OS using Windows' boot manager

Tags: release-freya

I want to install elementary OS, but I want to use the Windows boot manager to select which OS I want to boot into. Could you tell me the steps needed to make this possible?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a real answer to your question, but you can use GRUB 2 to manage your dual boot. I already did this by using GRUB 2. Here you can visit my blog (in french, sorry :/) but you can see a fully working exemple of this. https://www.florian-lacrampe.me/2015/01/09/windows-to-go-8-1-et-ubuntu-14-10-sur-un-ssd-portable-usb/ Steps if you want to use GRUB 2 : 1: Install a fresh elementay OS on a first portion of your hard disk 2: Install a fresh Windows 10 on the second part of the hard disk 3: Boot on elementary OS and use "[Grub customizer](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/grub-customizer)" to sett

Comment: Is this UEFI.If you have UEFI you can try rEFInd which is graphical and doesn't require Windows to be booted

Answer (score 1):

Judging by [this AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader) it could be done (**disclaimer**: I haven't tested this):

Assuming that Windows is already installed, install elementary OS on another partition. Make sure that you install Grub2 on the elementary OS  partition - don't install it on the MBR since this will overwrite the Windows boot-loader.

Boot into Windows and install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1)

Add Entry and choose Grub2 i.e.

[image]

Then write back the modified Windows Boot-loader i.e.

[image]

Reboot - you will now have two options (except it'll say whatever you want it to say instead of Ubunutu):

[image]

Boot into elementary OS and change the Grub Timeout value i.e.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` and save.

Finally:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Note that this won't turn off Grub, it'll just make it appear for 0 seconds, so you won't be able to see it.

Comment: If i already install eOS in MBR i need to reinstall windows or i can repair it with the installation disk ?